# How to mount an OLGA package IC for development

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, components, surface-mount, packages

I need to mount an IC with an OLGA package in a protoboard or wirewrapping board for development. There is no development kit in the manufacturer's website for this IC, so all I have is two samples of the IC. The package is a really small 14 pin OLGA, defined in [this diagram](http://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/land_patterns/90-0461.PDF).

What options do I have to mount this little IC? Maybe there is a PIN socket for this kind of package? Or the only option would be to layout a custom PCB?

Comment: [Deadbug?](https://youtu.be/q53uPn1mKc0?t=433)

Comment: If you know how, make a custom PCB. You'd get three PCBs for about $3 from [OSH Park](https://oshpark.com/pricing). Bring each pin to a pin header on 0.1" pitch, so it'll plug straight into a breadboard or stripboard. Make sure the pads for its footprint extend well beyond the edge of the chip to make it easier to solder. You might also put other components on the PCB, for example decoupling capacitors, to make it even easier to use. (If you don't yet know how to use ECAD to design a PCB, this might be a reasonable place to start, though it might take a few days to learn)

Answer (score 1):

Breakout board, custom breakout board, or dead bug.  Not sure if there are any boards available for that particular footprint, but you can always roll a basic breakout board through OSH park.  Rolling you own also gives you an opportunity to get the PCB footprint figured out.  If you don't care to wait for the turnaround, glue the chip to something (perfboard, an unused SMD breakout board of arbitrary footprint with enough pins, etc) and manually make the connections one at a time.